# Write-protect documentation for self-written Add-on package

Tags: front-end, documentation

My package works fine so far, and now I want to add some documentation. I have put a file in

`FileNameJoin[{
  $UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "myPkg", 
  "Documentation", "English", "Guides", "TableOfContents.nb"}]`.

The content of the notebook is:

```
    Notebook[{Cell["Table of Contents for pkgTools", "TOCDocumentTitle", 
       ShowGroupOpener -> False, TextAlignment -> Center], Cell[TextData[
        ButtonBox["Tutorial: CodingStandards", Rule[BaseStyle, "Link"], 
          Rule[ButtonData, "paclet:pkgTools/tutorial/CodingStandards"]]], 
       "TOCChapter", ShowGroupOpener -> True], Cell[TextData[
        ButtonBox["Tutorial: CreateNewApplication", Rule[BaseStyle, "Link"], 
          Rule[ButtonData, "paclet:pkgTools/tutorial/CreateNewApplication"]]], 
       "TOCChapter", ShowGroupOpener -> True], Cell[TextData[
        ButtonBox["Tutorial: ToDoList", Rule[BaseStyle, "Link"], 
          Rule[ButtonData, "paclet:pkgTools/tutorial/ToDoList"]]], "TOCChapter", 
       ShowGroupOpener -> True]}, StyleDefinitions -> 
      FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]]
```

Now when I load the package, it appears in the Function navigator under "Add-Ons". When I click on it, the notebook opens. But it gets immediately the "modified" Tag, which is confusing to users of the package who just want to read the documentation.

Is there a way to write-protect the documentation notebook?

Comment: Don't have time time, but one idea is setting Saveable -> False on the notebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Szabolcs mentioned, the standard way to write-protect a notebook is to set the option `Saveable -> False` when creating the notebook.

Needless to say: if you want to write fully professional documentation, *[Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/)*
 $\;$ is your best solution. It automatically creates write-protected documentation.